# How do I get question feed only with one tag (e.g. java)?

Tags: support, tags, search

I want to get the list of questions which are only tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Currently I am getting the list of all questions tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) + other tags in it.

For example, if there are two new questions with question Q1 ([java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)) and question Q2 ([java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading)), I want to get *only question Q1*, instead of both Q1 and Q2, which have the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176126/isolated-tag-search-questions-having-x-tag-only-and-nothing-else

Comment: Still it does not work. I think this feature is not available

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't do this in the Stack Overflow search facility - but you can create your own query in the data explorer to do the same thing if you really wished:

[Here is one I created as an example for you](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/463100/find-questions-containing-a-single-tag)

For those who cba with the link, here is the SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @tag nvarchar(250)

-- Choose which tag you want to search for here:
SET @tag = 'java'

SELECT TOP 10 Id AS [Post Link], Tags
FROM Posts
WHERE Tags = '<' + @tag + '>' AND PostTypeId = 1
ORDER BY LastActivityDate DESC
```

Comment: Excellent, this is what I am exactly looking for :)

Comment: Do know that you can use the magic column `[Post Link]` on `posts.id` to get the title and link in one go, as  shown [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/463128?tagname=java)

Comment: @rene I haven't played with the magic columns yet, but that's a perfect example of when to use one! I'll update the query - cheers :)

Comment: Sorry, completely separate from the answer, what does this mean: "... those who cba with the link..."?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan cba = "can't be arsed". Basically if people don't feel like following the link to see how the query works I posted the code to save them the effort. Just a couple less clicks :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm old, American, and lazy, so I cba to look up cba :)