# Syntax highlighting override doesn't work on iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, syntax-highlighting, ios-app

I posted [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320142/4240221)  today on meta and used the following to force the SQL syntax highlighting:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-sql -->
```

Which works as expected on desktop. However on the iOS app it seems to be doing it's own thing:

[image: screenshot]

Is it just me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.5.0.1.

The app was taking an extremely naïve approach and if the site supported pretty print just clobbering all the code blocks with either the tag language (from StackOverflow in a one-time sampling) or the site-specific language for the four sites that have it.  In reality, things are more nuanced.  MSO for example supports pretty print but only if you specify the language.

I'm now incorporating the logic from the web to factor in whether or not to highlight by default and using the exact same logic for populating the `prettyprint` and `lang-` classes on the `<pre>` elements.